# Total number of comparisons in Binary Insertion Sort Algorithm

Tags: sorting

I've built a custom [binary insertion sort algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-insertion-sort/) that relies on the user to make the comparison as to what is greater or not. I want to add a progress bar, which means I need a way of calculating the worst-case number of comparisons they will need to do.

I wasn't able to find anything online with a formula for calculating this, so I sat down to think about it practically and I *think* I came up with something that will return the correct response:

#### Python example

```
import math

def totalComparisons(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        total += math.floor((n-i)/2) + 1
    return total


print(totalComparisons(4))
```

This will return 5 for `n = 4`, which I believe is correct using the following practical example:

#### Practical example

```
[A, B, C, D]
1. A - B
2. C - B
3. C - A
4. D - B
5. D - A | D - C
```

Is this correct? Can this be boiled down to the following?

#### Formula

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lfloor{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}\rfloor + 1 $$

### Edit

The above started falling apart when `n > 6`, I believe this formula works:

#### Formula

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lfloor{(i-\lceil{\frac{i}{2}}\rceil)/2}\rfloor+2 $$

#### Python

```
def totalComparisons(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0;
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    total = 1
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        total += math.floor((i - math.ceil(i/2)) / 2) + 2
    return total


for i in range(13):
   print(f'Combinations for {i} items: {totalComparisons(i)}')

Comparisons for list length 0 items: 0
Comparisons for list length 1 items: 0
Comparisons for list length 2 items: 1
Comparisons for list length 3 items: 3
Comparisons for list length 4 items: 5
Comparisons for list length 5 items: 7
Comparisons for list length 6 items: 10
Comparisons for list length 7 items: 13
Comparisons for list length 8 items: 16
Comparisons for list length 9 items: 19
Comparisons for list length 10 items: 23
Comparisons for list length 11 items: 27
Comparisons for list length 12 items: 31
```

### Edit 2

#### Fixed Python to get the correct results as from joriki's answer

```
def totalComparisons(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0;
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    total = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        total += math.floor((i - math.ceil(i/2)) / 2) + 2
    return total

Comparisons for list length 0 items: 0
Comparisons for list length 1 items: 0
Comparisons for list length 2 items: 1
Comparisons for list length 3 items: 3
Comparisons for list length 4 items: 5
Comparisons for list length 5 items: 8
Comparisons for list length 6 items: 11
Comparisons for list length 7 items: 14
Comparisons for list length 8 items: 17
Comparisons for list length 9 items: 21
Comparisons for list length 10 items: 25
Comparisons for list length 11 items: 29
Comparisons for list length 12 items: 33
```

Comment: Since you don't describe your algorithm, we can't comment on how many comparisons it will take.  The sequence you give is not in OEIS.  How can it take $5$ for $3$ items?  There are only $3$ pairs to compare, so I strongly suspect your formula is incorrect.  Similarly for $4$ items, there are only $6$ pairs to compare.  And for $1$ it should not take any comparisons to sort it.

Comment: So where do you start comparing for the insertion?  If you start at one end, you may have to do all the comparisons there are, so there are $\frac 12(n^2-n)$.  If you start in the middle and do binary search each time there are many fewer.

Comment: I agree with @RossMillikan that you should describe the algorithm. This is a mathematics site, not a software site; you shouldn't expect everyone who may be able to answer your question to know all sorting algorithms. Also, there might be details of implementation that vary. The uncertainty is increased by the fact that your example doesn't seem to match the standard insertion sort as described at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

Comment: In the worst case, I would expect `ABCD` to be in reverse order; but then the first step would swap `AB` and the second step would compare `C` to `A`, not to `B`. Please clarify.

Comment: Please also address Ross' point that you seem to be counting more comparisons than there are pairs. This shouldn't happen in insertion sort, since each item is  only compared with items in front of it while being inserted and only with items behind it after being inserted, and so should only be compared to each other item at most once.

Comment: There was a bug in my Python code that had the offset of comparisons/list length off by 1. That's been fixed and updated.

Comment: @RossMillikan as for the original algorithm, I can provide that as well but it is the same as any other binary insertion sort algorithm (the user choice part here doesn't matter).

Comment: @joriki "Insertion sort" is similar, but different than "binary insertion sort" which is the original algorithm I'm using here.

Comment: Why did you write separate counting code instead of running your existing code on the worst case and counting the comparisons?

Comment: @joriki If I understand your question correctly, because I need to calculate the progress as a user proceeds through the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you refused our requests to make the question self-contained by describing your insertion algorithm, I’ll first describe it here as gleaned from the code you linked to. Next time you ask a question here, please do this yourself.

> In step $k$, insert the $(k+1)$-th item into the array of $k$ items already sorted. To find the appropriate place, perform a binary search of those $k$ items by comparing with the midpoint (rounded down, but that shouldn’t matter) and recursively applying the binary search to the upper or lower half as long as necessary.

In the worst case, each binary search requires $\left\lfloor\log_2k\right\rfloor+1$ comparisons. Thus the total number of comparisons in the worst case is

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\log_2k\right\rfloor+1
\\
&=&
\sum_{l=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}l2^{l-1}+(n-2^{\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor})(\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor+1)
\\
&=&
(\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor-1)2^{\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}+1+(n-2^{\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor})(\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor+1)
\\
&=&
n(\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor+1)-2^{\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor+1}+1
\;.
\\
\end{eqnarray}

Here’s a table of these values:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\\hline
a_n&0&1&3&5&8&11&14&17&21&25&29&33
\end{array}

The first deviation from your counts is at $a_5=8$. Here the four binary searches require $1$, $2$, $2$, $3$ comparisons in the worst case, so it seems $8$ is the correct answer. The only way to know for sure is to count the comparisons in the execution of the algorithm itself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did, once again, have an issue in the Python code which I fixed and was able to replicate the results you got here. I think my actual formula does work and give them same results yours does, but this gives me a good way to double check.

Comment: Also, I didn't mean to "refuse" to provide the binary insertion sort algorithm, I thought that the algorithm as linked from the website would explain it much better than I would. I certainly wouldn't have made it as clear as you did above.